# Can a library that uses CMake also be built with SCons?

Tags: cmake, scons

I want to use KDL (Kinematics and Dynamics Library) in robot control box. But robot control box uses SCons as their build system while KDL uses CMake.

It turned out that the control box doesn't have CMake installed. Should I install CMake in the control box? Or write SCons file for compiling KDL?

====================================================

My question is ambiguous. Sorry for that. And unfortunately, I cannot show the link of Control Box, it's not public. Here is link of KDL installation manual.

http://www.orocos.org/kdl/installation-manual

Let me make it more clear.

Forget all of previous question above and all about Control box, KDL. Let's say that you want to use one library. But the library can be built using CMake according to installation manual. Your PC doesn't have CMake installed but it has SCons, and unfortunately you should not install CMake on your PC.

If you can only use SCons, what can you do?

I know this situation is not usual, I want to know your opinion.

Comment: SCons is not a compiler, it's a build tool. I don't get your question. Have you installed CMake? Have you build ControlBox using SCons (and probably make)? Have you built KDL using CMake (and probably make)? Where did you have problems.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I have very few knowledge in build tool.

Comment: I built KDL using CMake in my PC, but not in ControlBox. Because Control Box doesn't have CMake. What makes me worry is this -> 'Is it ok to install cmake in Control Box?'. Control Box is built on their own linux kernel now. I'm afraid that the system of Control Box might break by my mistake.

Comment: I think there are two choices. First, install cmake in Control Box. Second, write sconscript for KDL and build KDL using scons. I want to know these two methods are possible. Thank you for answering.

Comment: I really don't understand your question. Are you asking about doing one compile on a PC running windows and then another on a machine you're calling "control box" which is some sort of linux box?  Can you post URL's to info about this "control box" as well as KDL?

Comment: Just install CMake. You could rewrite all the build system stuff with SCons, but that is really a major effort and I would advice you not try it. Back to CMake: Why should you not want installing it? It is really easy, can be done by every user and is light wight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your initial question: Yes, you should always try to install CMake, if that is a build requirement for you library and if you need to build that library from the sources.

To answer your later question: Replacing or rewriting the build system scripts is a major effort and not advisable. In general there is no script to convert build-systems. Such script might help to make the manual transformation. If you have a look at LLVM's effort to replace Autotools by CMake or Boost replacing it's own build system by CMake, you find out it takes several people several years and still not everybody is satisfied.

Often you don't need to build the library yourself. Either there are already built packages from the project directly of from your distribution (Debian etc. packages) or third party packagers like Mac Ports or NuGet.
In your case KDL provides Debian/Ubuntu packages.

Additional KDL is part of ROS, which is experimental in Homebrew for OS X.

Comment: Thank you @usr1234567. I'll try to install cmake. It seems that they provide Debian/Ubuntu as you mentioned. But I don't understand how to get it. They're saying KDL is part of ROS. But to me, it seems that **I have to install ROS to get KDL**. Is it right?

Comment: Probably ROS is way more as you want/need. I'd go with CMake.